# How to set model default value to a result bring returned by a function?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I've got a **function** inside my **model** which generates a random value for the **model field** and I need to set that value as a **default** for the **model field**.

I've got the following **model**

```
class Info(TimeStampedModel):
    info_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    generated_url = models.TextField(
        null=False, blank=False, default=random
    )

    def random(self):
        return 'customer.random.domain.com.' + ("".join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=5)))
```

I wish the **default value** for the **generated_url** to be coming from the **method** inside the **model** named as **random**.

but I get the following **exception** at **Runtime**:

```
TypeError: random() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

If I add **parenthesis** at the end of the **function** **name** as

```
generated_url = models.TextField(
            null=False, blank=False, default=random()
        )
```

Then in that case I get a **compile** time error as the **same**:

```
TypeError: random() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after reading the complete stack trace I was able to figure out that inside one of my **migrations** I had **random()** defined as a function inside the **model class** and the attribute **generated_uri** was pointing to that **internal method** so when I was trying to change the scope of **random()** from being inside the class to outside the class I was getting an exception which was coming from the **migrations** that the **attribute random() is not found in part of the object** so the solution to my problem was as.

- Revert all the migrations
- Remove the class function change its scope and place it outside the class
- Add a migration again
- Run the migration and it worked